# What does media="screen" mean in css?

Tags: css, media

What does media="screen" mean in the below css code?

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Comment: The first hit in Google for "css media screen" is http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html

Comment: The below code is not CSS, its HTML markup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The goal of the media attribute is to allow you to specify different styles for different methods of display.

Most commonly I use this to have 2 sets of styles, 1 for display (screen) and 1 for printing (print)

Normally on the "print" css I'll do things like hide buttons, strip out extraneous images, ads, etc etc.  Basically, make it 8.5x11 friendly.

Comment: "screen" are the styles that your average web-browsing user is going to see.  See the links that others have provided for what the various media types mean.

Answer (score 3):

There are two types, screen is the default browser view. print is for print view.

Comment: [CSS 2 defines 10 media types](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/media.html#media-types): all, braille, embossed, handheld, print, projection, screen, speech, tty and tv.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Brook's answer, the `media="foo"` attribute of the  is equivilant to the `@media foo` in your CSS file