# multiple media queries not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, boot

hey guys I don't quite get multiple media queries. here is what I mean

**html code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 id ="jumbo_text">{% block jumbo_text1 %} {% endblock %}</h1>
        <h2 id ="jumbo_text2">{% block jumbo_text2 %} {% endblock %}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css code:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and  (max-width: 767px) {
    .jumbotron {

        display: none;
    }
}   

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .jumbotron {

        height: 200px !important;
        width:300px;
        background-image: url("../../img/jumbo_pics/bbj_class.jpg");
    }

}
```

basically the second media query works but the first one doesn't. why?

**in pseudocode:**

```
devices that are at minium 200px and maximum 360px dont show jumbotron

devices above 360px but below 768px show jumbotron with height of 200px and width of 300px
```

Im really confused between `max-width` and `min-width` too

does `max-width` mean a device whose width is at max `n` and therefore all sizes below `n` the style applies?

and does `min-width` mean a device whose width at minimum is `n` and all the sizes above `n` the style applies?

am I getting that right?

**to wrap this up:**

1. how to do multiple media queries with different ranges?
2. is my understanding of `min-width` and `max-width` correct?

Answer (score 5):

The second media query appears later in the stylesheet, so it takes precedence. Since, you mentioned max-width:767px and max-width: 768px in both cases, they are overlapping in the range 200-768px and hence the second one which appears later has taken affect.

> devices above 360px but below 768px

You only mentioned max-width right? Min-width has not taken affect here. Media "screen" is a restriction on the device viewing the page, which in this case happens to be devices mostly other than "print".

There is a good discussion on media-queries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523865/what-does-media-screen-mean-in-css).

Also, media queries have the same specifity as other css rules. So, dont expect media query to take precedence over a css rule with same selectors, unless it appears later.

So, a good way to solve your problem would be to write it in this fashion.

```
.jumbotron{
/*for other device sizes
write styles here */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and  (max-width: 360px) {
    .jumbotron {
            display: none;
    }
}   

@media only screen and (min-width:361px) and (max-width: 768px){
    .jumbotron {
        height: 200px !important;
        width:300px;
        background-image: url("../../img/jumbo_pics/bbj_class.jpg");
    }

}
```

And your understanding of min-width and max-width is correct, however its always a good idea to use both of them in a media-query to ensure that ranges dont overlap and you end up with a rule which is not desirable.

Comment: can you show me a code snippet to visualize the correct way of doing it?

Comment: ok so like

in relation to the pseudocode in my post

to write that in css how would that look like?